# Does Jacob's Well in present-day Nablus/Shechem have a Jewish tradition associated with it?

Tags: history, eretz-yisrael, avot-patriarch-fathers, geography

There's a well in present-day Shechem (Nablus) called "Jacob's Well."  It has an Orthodox Christian church on top of it right now.  I was wondering if there is any Jewish tradition that Jacob dug this particular well or if it's only a Christian religious site.  (I'm aware that he buys land in Shechem in [Bereshit 33:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0133.htm), but it says nothing of digging a well there.)

[Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob%27s_Well#Religious_significance) lists a source that says Jewish tradition does associate this well with Jacob, but it's not a Jewish source.  I've done a bit of research but can't find anything reliable – though I also don't know Hebrew.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Caroline. Interesting question. Hope to see you around. :)

Answer (score 2):

In [Seder Hadorot, year 2514](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A3_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99), it says:

> "...כתב גא"י נבלוס הוא שכם ובכפר אלבצנו רבא נקבר יוסף הצדיק וחומות יפים סביב קברו ועמוד אחד לצד ראשו ואחד לצד רגלו ונגד שכם הוא הר גריזים והר עיבל ובין הר עיבל הוא קבר יוסף ושם בארי מים חיים נקראים עין יעקב..."

Translation: "Glilot Eretz Yisrael<sup>1</sup> [wrote](http://file:///C:/Users/marsh/Downloads/Hebrewbooks_org_36601.pdf) that Nablus is Shechem and in the village of Albatzanu Rava Yosef is buried and there are beautiful walls around his grave, one at the head of his grave and one at the foot of his grave, and opposite of Shechem is Mt. Gerizzim and Mt. Eval, and between Mt. Eval is the grave of Yosef and by there are wells of the water of life that are called Ein Yaakov..."

---

<sup>1</sup> A 17th century book on places in the Land of Israel by R' Gershon ben Eliezer Segal. There's a disagreement in what language it was originally written, but eventually it was translated into Hebrew and called Iggeret Hakodesh.